# Passing class variable to custom listeners

Tags: java, android

im kinda stuck with my programming.

I'll try my best to explain my problem:
At the moment i have one class that stores data and has getter/setter methods.
There're several variables in that class, mostly booleans/ints and a few floats.

In my MainActivty layout i have a simple textview,seekbar and an edittext. 
Looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeZW6.png

Now, i created two custom Listener. One OnSeekBarChangeListener and one TextWatcher. What they do is, if i change the value on the seekbar, it sets the text of the edittext to the progress of the seekbar. And the other one sets the progress of the seekbar to the input value of the corresponding edit text.

The constructor of the textwatcher class gets the EditText, a SeekBar and an object of my data class "Config" as parameters.
The listener for the seekbar only gets an EditText and the Config object as parameters.
I want to keep the listeners as modular as possible because i'll have to reuse them alot.

Obviously if theres more than one row in the main layout, i have to save different seekbar progress and edittext inputs in different variables of the config object.

Herein lies my problem, i simply can't figure out how to pass the different variables of a config object to the listeners i.e. in the code below i create a Config object "defaultConfig" that object has an int VKCode. I would like to be able to tell the listeners that it should save to that specific variable within the object.

My Code:

Config Class:

```
public class Config {
    private int VKCode;

    public Config() {
    }

    public int getVKCode() {
        return VKCode;
    }

    public void setVKCode(int VKCode) {
        this.VKCode = VKCode;
    }

}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SeekBar sbVKCode;
private EditText etVKCode;
private Config defaultConfig;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sbVKCode = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sb_vkcode);
    etVKCode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_vkcode);
    etVKCode.setText(Integer.toString(0));

    defaultConfig = new Config();

    sbVKCode.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new CustomSeekBarChangeListener(etVKCode,defaultConfig));
    etVKCode.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextChangeListener(etVKCode, sbVKCode,defaultConfig));
  }
}
```

CustomSeekBarChangeListener:

```
public class CustomSeekBarChangeListener implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private EditText editText;
private Config config;

public CustomSeekBarChangeListener(EditText e, Config c) {
    editText = e;
    config = c;
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    config.setVKCode(progress); //I want to be able to set to which variable it saves the progress within the config class
    editText.setText(Integer.toString(progress));
    Log.i("VKCode", Integer.toString(progress));
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

   }
}
```

Custom TextWatcher:

```
public class CustomTextChangeListener implements TextWatcher {
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;
private Config config;
private EditText editText;
private SeekBar seekBar;

public CustomTextChangeListener(EditText e, SeekBar sb, Config c) {
    handler = new Handler();
    editText = e;
    seekBar = sb;
    config = c;
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (editText.getText().toString() != "") {
                try {
                    int prog = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());
                    seekBar.setProgress(prog);
                    config.setVKCode(prog); //Here the same, i want to be able to set the variable it saves prog in via. the constructor of this TextWatcher
                    Log.i("VKCODE","" + config.getVKCode());
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                }
            }
        }
    };
}


@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,500);
   }
}
```

I hope my explanation makes sense, i want to achieve fully independent listeners that i can use on any SeekBar/EditText and be able to tell it what variable it should save the progress/input to.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

cheers

Comment: When do you want to set the variable to use? What about using a map and passing the key within the constructor? Would that answer your question? If you want to choose a specific setter or field you may have to use reflection; I don't see how you could do that without (unless you call each setter individually, e.g. from a large `switch`).

Comment: Well what i ultimately try to achieve is that i'll be able to parse a xml file(~2000 lines) from a server and save the ~1000 different variables to the config object.The purpose of the app is to edit a xml config used by a different windows application. Each of the variables will have one of those rows in the layout, with either a textview/switch for booleans or a textview/seekbar/edittext for ints/floats. So i'll probably set the listeners in the oncreate of the fragment/activity they are used in. And also, since i just got into java/android it would probably be easiest to use a big switch.

Comment: Using a `Map` such as a `HashMap` would certainly be best in this case. You don't go for a 1000 line switch. For repetitive tasks you use your computer, not the other way around.

Comment: How would you go about implementing that if you dont mind me asking? I know the basic workings of a HashMap, but do you mean i should store the variables in a HashMap, pass that to the listener and access the different variables via. the key? Kinda confused here, but i really appreciate the help :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I got what you are trying to do, lets see if you can understand & use this scheme:

```
package nl.owlstead.stackoverflow;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ListenerToConfiguredVariable {

    // this could also be some kind of SeekBar or it could simply call it
    private final Handler handlerSeekBar = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleValue(String value) {
            System.out.println("SeekBar : " + value);
        }

    };

    // this could also be some kind of EditText or it could simply call it
    private final Handler handlerEditText = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleValue(String value) {
            System.out.println("EditText : " + value);
        }

    };

    private Map<String, Handler> map;

    {
//        createMapManually();
        createMapUsingReflection();
    }

    private void createMapManually() {
        Map<String, Handler> theMap = new HashMap<>();
        theMap.put("handlerSeekBar", handlerSeekBar);
        theMap.put("handlerEditText", handlerEditText);
        map = java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(theMap);
    }

    private void createMapUsingReflection() {
        Map<String, Handler> theMap = new HashMap<>();

        // iterate over all fields
        Field[] declaredFields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : declaredFields) {
            // we only want the handlers, not any other field
            if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Handler.class)) {
                try {
                    theMap.put(field.getName(), (Handler) field.get(this));
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            }
        }
        map = java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap(theMap);
    }

    interface Handler {
        void handleValue(String value);
    }

    public static class Config {
        public String getConfiguredVariable() {
            return "handlerSeekBar";
        }
    }

    public ListenerToConfiguredVariable() {
        Config config = new Config();
        // the for loop simulates reading all the values from the XML file
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // this would be inside the listener
            String var = config.getConfiguredVariable();
            Handler handler = map.get(var);
            handler.handleValue(Integer.toString(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ListenerToConfiguredVariable();
    }
}
```

It uses a Map to different handlers, and it calls the handlers given a configuration string.

Comment: Note that this does use some kind of indirection. You can of course also let your Config instance directly return a configured handler. But strings are easier to put into a Config instance.

Comment: Hey, thanks alot man! I rewrote the data layer of the application, its alot easier doing it your way!